# Can a 'Blade Barrier' turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Blade Barrier](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/bladeBarrier.html#_blade-barrier) spell can be a **Wall** or a **Ring** without stating if the Wall has to be a straight line. Can the Wall have a curve or a turn in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.**

[Blade Barrier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blade-barrier)'s effect line lacks the Shape-able (S) tag. This means that its shape cannot be changed and so it must be either a straight line or a circle.

By contrast, look at the effect line of [Wall of Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone). There, the (S) tag means you can shape its area (see the [magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic) section of PFSRD) within the limits stated by the spell.

> **(S) Shapeable**
>   If an area or effect entry ends with “(S),” you can shape the spell. a shaped effect or area can have no dimension smaller than 10 feet. Many effects or areas are given as cubes to make it easy to model irregular shapes. Three-dimensional volumes are most often needed to define aerial or underwater effects and areas.

Comment: Dang, I just learned something!  Good on you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say and there's no official effect definition of "wall."  I would tend to rule that it must be flat, because it seems cheesy to stack it thick or whatever to create a "zone of blades" - that would be a higher level spell in my estimation!